# How to add checkbox as label for TableGrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editablegrid

I have react js file which is displaying table date with table grid , and the layout for is kind of below

```
 class ABC extends Component {

   constructor (props)    {
      super (props);
      this.state = {

        tableGridDetails : [
            {label: 'Name' key : 'name' width: '4'}
            {label: 'Age' key : 'age' width: '4'}
            {label: '' key : 'ShowCheckBox' width: '4'}     
           ]
     
        }
    }

}
```

So **key** here is variable name which is coming from API and displaying there !

Now for last label,in key I have added checkbox with ShowCheckBox which is working fine and added checkbox in 3rd column

however, instead of **Label**, I want to show **Checkbox** there which on clicking of it , select all other checkbox !

i am not sure how I can add checkbox here !

Can someone please help here?

Thanks